# What JavaServlet is used for the Solr Instace within Laradock?

Tags: servlets, solr, laradock

i know that we use jetty as java servlet container on our staging/production servers but what is the java servlet container within laradock when it comes to solr? overall im only familiar with jetty/tomcat but those i cant find. we had to adjust the servlet configuration on staging but i would need those settings in the dev environment too.

and in case someone already had that problem within laradock - on staging we adjusted the

```
requestHeaderSize
```

from the default 8k to 64k bytes so the length of the uri is no issue anymore. and now we also need that setting within laradock/solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Dockerfile for laradock/solr](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/solr/Dockerfile) it builds using the regular 5.5 Solr image with minimal changes.

Solr uses a bundled, internal Jetty version since dropping support for other containers in Solr 5.

In general there should be no reason to change the `requestHeaderSize` for a Solr installation, as you can use `POST` requests instead of `GET` for any Solr request that contains a large request body (i.e. which usually happens if you have many boolean arguments).

Your Solr client should default to using `POST` instead of `GET` for requests.

Comment: i did not manage to get solarium to use default POST, do you know solarium and maybe have a hint in the direction of using POST as default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198367/how-to-configure-solarium-to-use-post-instead-of-get-requests